# Got "The type java.lang.CharSequence cannot be resolved" error when compile JasperReports template

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I use Netbeans 8.1 and iReport 5.5.0 plugin. I made a change in my report field.

```
$F{SASI_NO}.contains("-E")?$F{SASI_NO}.split("-")[0]:$F{SASI_NO}
```

It works fine in my local. But I deployed it in a server. It did not work and the error is like below.

> javax.servlet.ServletException: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Errors were encountered when compiling report expressions class file:
>   1. The type java.lang.CharSequence cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
>                   value = ((java.lang.String)field_SASI_NO.getValue()).contains("-E")?((java.lang.String)field_SASI_NO.getValue()).split("-")[0]:((java.lang.String)field_SASI_NO.getValue()); //$JR_EXPR_ID=31$

anyone help?

Comment: The issue described here: [JRXML not compiling in Java 8](http://community.jaspersoft.com/jasperreports-library/issues/3498-0). The bug of JasperReports was fixed at 6.x version

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a solution. My windows server's Java version was 1.8.0.121. I downgrade Java to 1.7 version.

---

The issue described here: [JRXML not compiling in Java 8](http://community.jaspersoft.com/jasperreports-library/issues/3498-0).

This bug of *JasperReports* library was fixed at 6.0 version

Comment: There is no jasper plugin except version 5.5.0 for netbeans.